# Bus for 15 person from Bergamo to Venice

Tags: transportation, italy, venice, bergamo

Looking for bus to transfer 15-16 person from Bergamo Apt to Venice. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you elaborate? Are you looking for private shuttles, or public transport?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Travel.SE! Please review the FAQ session for better understanding how to ask a question here. http://travel.stackexchange.com/tour